# OpenFlipper fails to compile, unable to find Qt

Tags: qt, compilation, cmake

On [its website](https://www.openflipper.org/media/Documentation/OpenFlipper-1.0-RC3/buildingOpenFlipper.html) OpenFlipper says it can be compiled in three steps as:

```
cd build
cmake ..
make     # or, even better, make -j8
```

However I get an error saying Qt is unable to be found at the `cmake` step and that I should specify a `QT5_INSTALL_PATH`. However even if I do this OpenFlipper is still issuing the same complaint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You are not supposed to specify where Qt is installed in the `QT5_INSTALLED_DIR` but prior to that as environment variable in your terminal:

  ```
  # assuming Qt was installed in your home directory, as is default
  export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=~/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/
  # note that you now have to call cmake etc from that process
  ```

- Compiling and running it after that you might get errors telling you `GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object` is not present, even if your `glxinfo | grep ARB_vertex_buffer` is telling you it is.* Clicking "Ignore" results in a crash. To mitigate this, you have to manually change `(4,3)` to `(3,0)` in

  ```
  OpenFlipper/widgets/coreWidget/CoreWidget.cc
  ```

- If you still experience errors, try deleting your cmake cache, this is accomplished by using `cmake-gui` (was in the package `cmake-qt-gui` for me) and hitting "Delete Cache"
- (optional) remove the very annoying warning message you get at every start of OpenFlipper by removing the line concerning "renderers shipped" in

  ```
  OpenFlipper/Core/Core.cc
  ```

---

*: My teaching assistant told me that there is a bug in Qt (<5.9) that forces OpenFlipper to use the *OpenGL Compatibility Profile*. Additionally Intel and AMD drivers hand back an *OpenGL 3.0 Core Context* when asked for an *OpenGL 4.3 Compatibility Context* (my TA described this behavior as a "bug", I'm not so sure about this), leading to a crash in Qt. So this should be resolved in Qt 5.9 (not out yet). This seems to affect also mainly integrated graphics, so one could try using a dedicated GPU.